# Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist for django application

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed Django application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk server.
I have .extensions folder and there I have wrote django.config file.
In django.config file have following code.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
```

When I deploy django application then showing **Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.**

Comment: What does the top-level of your project directory look like? Is there a `ebdjango` directory at the top-level?